# Deteccion de objetos en Listas de R

Tags: r, lista, rstudio

hola tengo este resultado de una lista como se ve en la siguiente comando.

```
 acti2945$data$data$additional_data
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
[[3]]$old_value_formatted
[1] "Contacto establecido"

[[3]]$new_value_formatted
[1] "Reunión hecha"


[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL

[[7]]
NULL

[[8]]
NULL

[[9]]
NULL

[[10]]
NULL

[[11]]
NULL

[[12]]
NULL

[[13]]
NULL

[[14]]
NULL

[[15]]
[[15]]$old_value_formatted
[1] "Cliente"

[[15]]$new_value_formatted
[1] "Contacto establecido"


[[16]]
NULL

[[17]]
list()
```

quisiera saber si hay una forma evaluar si hay un valor en cada uno de la listas . Seria mucha ayuda . ya que en mas adelante se podria sacar los old_value_formatted o new_value_formatted (uno de los dos) pero sin perder los demas valores (es decir colocarlo en un vector con sus nulos sin perder el orden de como va lista) original . Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo un ejemplo similar al que has dado:

```
list(NULL, 
     NULL, 
     list(old_value_formatted="Contacto establecido",
          new_value_formatted="Reunión hecha"),
     list()
     ) -> lista
```

Para saber los elementos que tienen un valor esperable, que parece ser otra lista con más de un elemento, podrías hacer:

```
sapply(lista, length) > 0

[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Ahora, si específicamente quieres ver si dentro de las posibles listas existe un elemento con un determinado nombre:

```
sapply(lista, function(x) any(names(x) == "old_value_formatted"))

[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

O bien, si además este elemento tiene un determinado valor:

```
sapply(lista, function(x) any(x$old_value_formatted == "Contacto establecido"))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Y por último, si quieres filtrar estos elementos en una nueva lista, puedes hacer un simple "slice" con el vector de lógicos obtenido en los anteriores casos, por ejemplo:

```
lista[sapply(lista, function(x) any(names(x) == "old_value_formatted"))]

[[1]]
[[1]]$old_value_formatted
[1] "Contacto establecido"

[[1]]$new_value_formatted
[1] "Reunión hecha"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me ayudo mucho.